# Studio 3T mongodb aggregation issue

Tags: sql, database, studio3t

I'm trying to find the user with the most friends from a **Yelp** dataset on **studio3t** using **mongodb**. I am using **studio3t's** aggregation tool.

First I selected "`name`" and "`friends`" with `$project`

Next, I wanted to group by the name of each user, and then sum the number of friends that correspond to that user

```
{
    _id : "$name",
    numberoffriends: {$sum : "$friends"}
}
```

However, I get a result that returns the names but returns a sum value of 0 for each name, which isn't correct.

Should I be using a **sum operator**? or is there a better operator for this function such as count?

Comment: add mongodb tag as well and share your work what you tried till now.  

Share sample data and expected result as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Friends` value is not integer. So `$sum` will not work.
Try using `$count` instead of `$sum` which will count the number of records

Comment: $count returns an error message, Im going to try and use $size

Comment: Its not sure from the question that value of friends key is a string or list...Can you share a sample document?